# Amazon Elastic Beanstalk fault recovery

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, amazon-ebs

I have a running Amazon Elastic Beanstalk environment. 
Sometimes it runs into problems and the load balancer kills my ec2 instance and starts a new one. I don't know how to create an "AMI" or template so the load balancer starts a new ec2 instance which is exactly like the one that I have configured.

Also, I attached some EBS blocks and I want to be able to create a new instance with a EBS block attached.

How can I do that? 
I read the documentation but I cannot find what I need, and I think this is a common scenario.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You should use `.ebextensions` to configure your Elastic Beanstalk instances. http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/customize-containers.html

These configurations and dependencies are handled on instance start-up.

Comment: I am a bit lost on that. Can I configure the EBS blocks there? Do you have any examples ? What about everything that I copied to the instance? Isn't it better to build an AMI ?

Comment: Building a custom AMI is no longer supported in Elastic Beanstalk. Also, "EBS" stands for "Elastic Block Store" and _not_ "Elastic Beanstalk". So I'm not sure what an "EBS block" is. Do you mean an [EBS Volume](https://aws.amazon.com/ebs/)? Or some kind of Elastic Beanstalk configuration?

Comment: I mean a EBS Volume. I have my Beanstalk environment, which has a EC2 instance, where a EBS Volume is mounted. I don't want to lose that configuration.